# How can Find and Replace with WildCard Number in Xcode

Tags: xcode, replace

I'm having problems using the Find and Replace with Wildcards in Xcode. I found this post here: [Xcode Wildcard characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272072/xcode-wildcard-characters)

However it is not working for me I'm thinking because of the older version of Xcode. I'm trying to find instances like these 3 different lines:

```
playerCardThirteenSlot = 6;
playerCardThirteenSlot = 7;
playerCardThirteenSlot = 8;
```

and in the find field am using

```
playerCardThirteenSlot = ([0-9]+);
```

which is not working. I just want to replace it with a blank string.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set Regular expression mode
Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Enter the regular expression:
[image]

The selected text:
[image]

If part of what is being searched for includes regular expression special characters they must be escaped.
String to match for different last digits:

if ([compCardThirteenTitle isEqualToString:[compHandNamesArray objectAtIndex:12]])
if ([compCardThirteenTitle isEqualToString:[compHandNamesArray objectAtIndex:13]])
if ([compCardThirteenTitle isEqualToString:[compHandNamesArray objectAtIndex:14]])

Regular expression to match:

```
if \(\[compCardThirteenTitle isEqualToString:\[compHandNamesArray objectAtIndex:1[2-4]\]\]\)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think my problem is that I am not searching for a regular expression, is there a work around if I want to search for something like:    if ([compCardThirteenTitle isEqualToString:[compHandNamesArray objectAtIndex:12]]) … and then find all the numbers at objectAtIndex?

Comment: I'm really just trying to do erase a bunch of code. I started the app with 15 "cards" and want to reduce it to 12. So I have been cutting lines like:  if ([compCardThirteenTitle isEqualToString:[compHandNamesArray objectAtIndex:12]]) … because "compCardThirteenTitle doesn't exist anymore, however the objectAtIndex can vary so I'm looking to wipe all the lines at once.